# Get encompassing class, then access a property of it inside custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and implementing custom validation via custom attributes/data annotations on my models.

Is it possible to access a property on an object's parent class inside my custom attribute?

```
public class MyModel
{
    [MyCustomValidator]
    public string var1 {get; set;}
    public string var2 {get; set;}
}
```

Note: Using asp.net mvc

```
public class MyCustomValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool override IsValid(Object value)
    {  
          // somehow get access to var2 in the MyModel
    }
}
```

So basically, making validation check another property for a specific value. I tried to pass `var2`'s value as a parameter to `MyCustomValidator` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Updated answer re your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, MVC 2 Validation doesn't support `validationContext` because MVC 2 targets DA 3.5. I'm not sure if this is still the case with MVC 2 RC, I'm using VS 2010 with MVC 2 Preview 1.

Taken from Brad Wilson's post at http://forums.asp.net/p/1457591/3650720.aspx

> There is no validation context in the 3.5 SP1 version of DataAnnotations, which is what MVC 2 targets. The [CustomValidation] attribute is also an artifact of DA4.0, so to write a custom validation, you need to create a new validation attribute derived from ValidationAttribute

Answer (score 3):

No, basically. After a hunt through reflector, you only have access to the *value* of the member being tested - not the containing object or even the member-info of the property/field/whatever.

Which I agree is very limiting and frustrating, but it looks like this is fixed in 4.0 - my previous reply *hinted* at this, but in 4.0 there is an [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022(VS.100).aspx) overload that accepts a [`ValidationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext(VS.100).aspx), which provides this infomation via [`ObjectInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationcontext.objectinstance(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Doesn't `ObjectInstance` refer to the object that is decorated with the said attribute? Also, I can't seem to override Validate, it doesn't show up. Only IsValid(object value) shows up.

Comment: When I do `protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)`, validationContext is always null.

Comment: @Baddie - well that is even *more* frustrating. You could log as an issue on "connect"?

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to say that you can do this with MVC3:

```
public class MyCustomValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool override IsValid(Object value)
    {  
          var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as MyModel; 
          // would probably use reflection and pass property names instead of casting in real life

          if (model.var2 != null && value == null)
          {
            return new ValidationResult("var1 is required when var2 is set");
          }

          return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```